# How do I change Meteor server-side data and re-publish to React Native app?

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb, meteor, react-native

I am trying to set up Meteor as a back-end server for a React Native (so far just Android) app, and have used [React Native Meteor Boilerplate](https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-meteor-boilerplate#react-native-meteor-boilerplate) as a starting point, in which I set up the server on a local port, then connect to it on the device. While the Meteor client/server interface is very dynamic, I'm confused as to why the app doesn't update with changes to the server code. For instance:

```
var seed = () => {
 if (Details.find().count() === 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Details.insert({
    name: `Detail #${i}`
  });
. . .
```

displays in the app a listview of items Detail #0, Detail #1, etc. But if I change this code, say by deleting the word 'Detail,' the app momentarily shows a loading icon, but then re-displays the same list...even if I restart the server and/or log out and back in to the app.

How do I change the data on the server so that it is reflected on the app? Is it cached somehow so that my changes aren't shown? Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you leave the Server running, and open another terminal and run `meteor shell` in your app's directory.  In this shell try and execute `Details.insert({name: 'Testing 1, 2, 3'})` and check if your client receives the new item.

Comment: Also if you already have items in Details, this code will not change the list.  Is that why it 're-displays the same list'?

Comment: @JeremyK -- thanks for the response, and yes, when I do Details.insert it updates on the app..woohoo! Clearly I just need to learn more about working with MongoDB. If you post an answer of "Learn Mongo!" and maybe include a good link I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your listview is showing you items from the Details collection, and there are items in it, `Details.find().count() === 0` evaluates to `false`, so the collection is not actually changing.
I suspect that is why you state that it 're-displays the same list'

An easy way to debug what is happening with your collections is to use the [Meteor Shell](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorshell), where you can add, delete, or modify items in your collections while observing what happens on the client.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot that once those documents were inserted that part of the function would never be evaluated again...oops. Thanks for the Shell tip as well, I can see there's lots to learn about both Meteor and MongoDB, and I'm sure any way of looking 'under the hood' will come in handy...thanks again!